# Force download video in webview on click button

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm using webview in android app, I play video and create link to download video but every time I click on download the video starts playing instead of downloading

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" download>Download</a>
```

Is there any solution for this?

```
    WebView myWebView = new WebView(activityContext);
    setContentView(myWebView);
```

Comment: Can you add your code from webview activity/class ???

Comment: i have added it @W4R10CK

Comment: I am asking about the whole activity code, where u have function for button click, variable initialisation.

Comment: i'm working on web pages  portal html&javascript there i display the video and i call this portal inside app by web-view